# Word 2016: How to reference a property of an external document?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2016, docx

I want to include a property of an external word document from within a word document. The property of the external doc is subject to regular change. There's information available on how to include text and other content via bookmarks with the INCLUDETEXT field code (described [here](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/TblsFldsFms/includetextfields.htm), for instance). But Is it possible to include a **property** of an external word document directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid your needs won't be met.

As far as I know, word's OOTB feature will only display the properties of this document directly.

"Quick parts" - "Field"

[image]

The method in the link you provide seems to be a good alternative, and we don't have any other way to do that.

(If you're good at code, maybe VBA is a good way to do it.)

Comment: This appears to be the case, without using VBA. I've ended up using a bookmark in the referenced document.